# error AH01630 only from specific ip

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, ubuntu-12.04, http-status-code-403, forbidden

some days ago an user report a specifical issue to access to our wordpress site stored in an apache2.4 running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  If he try to access from the office, obtain a 403 error and the logs show "AH01630: client denied by server" but if try to access from another connection (other office, his home or any different of the office where work), can access without any problem.

We have published others 2 sites in the same server, all with the same vhost configuration (obviusly changing the ServerName and root Directory), and that 2 sites work perfectly from anywhere, including the office where cant access to the first site.

I disable fail2ban in the server, and confirm to IPV6 is disabled too.  I dont have any .htaccess ban rule and the last server configuration changes was done 3 months ago, but this issue just have 3 days.  I check all the logs and the previous logs (four days ago and before) report complete access to the site from the office where report the issue.

Thanks in advance for any sugestion to find the solution.

Regards.

Comment: Showing the complete line of that error message may give more clues and get you an answer.

Comment: Does the client IP address/hostname shown in the server logs match the expected one? Has this changed since it was working? If you're sure that nothing has changed at the server side the implication must be that something at the client end has changed (or the network routing in between).

Comment: Do you have `hosts` or `localhost` setting on the office network or client machines (perhaps set up for testing, etc.) that is directing these requests somewhere else?

Comment: This is the log reported:

        [Thu May 26 19:34:38.192186 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 18397] [client public.ip.office.address:47043] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/documents, referer: https://www.google.com.co/
        [Thu May 26 19:34:38.323288 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 18397] [client public.ip.office.address:47043] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/favicon.ico, referer: http://www.companydomain.net/documents/internal-procedures/

Comment: From the office side i cant found any log related with the connection issue.  Remember to they access to anothers 2 sites in the same webserver and dont have any issues;  all are specifically to the **specifical site** from **that** office.

I do directly the test from the linux router used by **that** office, and report the same answer.

We do a test with 3 users laptop localized on **that** office.  If they try access using the office connection, get the **_forbidden_** error using wired or wifi local connection; but if they use a movile shared connection, access correctly to the site.

Comment: Of all of these "outside" locations that do get access, are any Windows machines and, in particular, are they able to access/download the `favicon.ico` file?

Comment: yes. all are windows machine and they have authorization to access/download the favicon.ico file